# bash: check if a variable is set AND has a certain value

Tags: bash, variables

I am a bit puzzled that I was not able to find the answer for this. There are countless results and answers for if a variable is set or not set, if it is set and non-empty and all the combinations.

But here's my case:

I have a function which was already working well, but now I have to extend the functionality to check on a parameter.

```
check_endpoints() {
  for (( i=0; i < $ENDPOINTS; i+=1 )); do
    // query an endpoint with curl, process and check the result
  done
}
```

Until now I had to check all the endpoints. However, now in a test I now want to tear down an endpoint randomly; I know which one I killed, so I want to skip checking that endpoint to avoid misleading output (i.e. the check would obviously fail).

Therefore I am passing a parameter to the function.

How do I check that a parameter is set and does not have a certain value?

I tried

```
  if [ -n $1 ] && [ $1 -eq $i ] ; then    
    echo "param 1 is equal" #continue in the loop  
  else    
    echo "not equal"        #run curl and all that
  fi
```

But this (somehow un-intuitively) seems to evaluate both brackets. I.e. when `$1` is empty, the second bracket evaluates it to an empty variable, and I get

`[: -eq: unary operator expected`

It does the right thing (it prints "not equal") but I'd like to get rid of the error.

Ideally I'd like a portable solution (please point to current non-portability if it exists, thanks), but it is not a must.

Comment: Quotes matter. Use them. `[ -n "$1" ]` -- and `-eq` is only for math; use `=` for general string comparisons.

Comment: Even if I am checking for an integer?? Note that $i is the integer variable of the iteration `for (( i=0;...))`

Comment: When you don't have quotes and `$1` is empty, `[ -n $1 ]` turns into `[ -n ]` which is true (because the default operation when `test` is given only one argument is `-n` so you get `[ -n "-n" ]`); whereas `[ -n "$1" ]` turns into `[ -n "" ]`, which is false.

Comment: As for `-eq` vs `=`, it depends on how you want failure modes to be handled. Do you want `[ three -eq 1 ]` to check `"$three"` to see if _that's_ a valid integer, or just to say it's false? If you want it to just be false, do it as a string comparison instead of an integer comparison in the first place.

Comment: BTW, when you speak to portability -- do you want sh-compatible code? You have bash-only syntax in your `for` loop; the POSIX-y equivalent is `i=-1; while i=$((i + 1)); [ "$i" -lt "$endpoitns" ]; do ...; done` (re: the variable being lower-case, see naming conventions in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- all-caps space is used for variables meaningful to the shell and OS)

Comment: I see. This works: `[ -n "$1" ] && [ $1 -eq $i ]`. So I want to `continue` in the loop if `$1 == $i`. The parameter is a number, e.g. `check_endpoints 2`. Does this mean that regardless, the `2` here is interpreted as a string first?

Comment: I'd still make it `[ "$1" -eq "$i" ]`; no reason to tempt fate. Any time you leave an expansion unquoted you're telling the shell to word-split it on IFS characters and then expand each result as a glob. Sure, you might _expect_ IFS will contain only whitespace, and you might _expect_ that your string will only ever match the regex `^[[:digit:]]+$` (containing at least one digit and nothing but digits), but why introduce new and surprising failure modes (vs relatively straightforward ones with clear error messages) if your expectations are ever wrong?

Comment: The whole thing that led to this question, "unary operator expected", was an example of a case where fragile code led to a confusing error message instead of a clear and descriptive one; get in habits of always getting the quoting (and other details) right and you hit fewer of those cases. (Consider using https://shellcheck.net/, which is locally installable -- the editor I use, [Helix](https://helix-editor.com/), automatically runs it as part of the [bash language server](https://github.com/bash-lsp/bash-language-server))

Comment: And yes, all shell variables are strings (subject to exceptions for some non-POSIX extensions that generally aren't worth talking about) -- even an array will act like a string (with only its first element) when you refer to it using regular string-dereferencing syntax. You can use them in a context where they're treated as numbers, but they're still strings under the hood.

Comment: OK clear. Thanks for the extensive explanations.